# Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'manageObjectContext'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I would like to print Data from CoreData in TableView for an iOS Application in Swift 3.

In the ListTableViewController file I've this code :

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let contxt :NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let freq = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Location")


    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

On the let context line, I've a error : "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'manageObjectContext'"

Have you an idea about my problem ?

Thank's

Comment: `appDel.managedObjectContext!` should be simply `managedObjectContext!`, no?

Comment: even without the `!`, simply `let contxt : NSManagedObjectContext = managedObjectContext`, since it is not an optional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error indicating that you don't assign any value into variable name managedObjectContext in Appdeleget. First, you have to define a variable and then assign a ManagedObjectContext object into it. But you can get the ManagedObjectContext object reference by below code as well as.

```
let managedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext as! NSManagedObjectContext
let contxt = managedObjectContext
```

Comment: but persistent container is for iOS 10.0 what about iOS 9.0